# How to view current users with Performance Monitor?

Tags: performance, iis, service, monitor

Tinkering with Performance Monitor, I see:

- Web Service -> Current Connections
- Web Service -> Get Requests/sec

Are there better counters to look at?  Or perhaps other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the image below, using Web Services -> Get Requests/sec is mostly sufficent for my needs.  But, I was hoping on something more elaborate.

But considering how this is free, can't beat free.

[alt text http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/3-webservers.png](http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/3-webservers.png)

Comment: yeah, sorry... websites tend to change after nearly 10 years.  :)

Comment: It's still the only tool I use on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For monitoring a small internal website you can view "Current Connections", also within the "Web Service" object.  Keep in mind this is active connections, not users and a single user can hold multiple connections open.  For example in my SharePoint 2010 environment each user makes 6 connections.